# Fixture finder methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fixtures

I have two models: `User`, `Group`

I have fixtures for both of them.

I have `UserTest` class which is unitTest and I can use fixture finder users(:someuserfixture). However, if I try to use groups(:somegroupfixture) it says that groups isn't recognized.

How can I access fixtures of another model?

---

Comment: Please provide code from your file where the tests are specified

Answer (score 0):

Generally people have this line in their `test/test_helper.rb` file:

```
fixtures :all
```

Which loads all the fixtures for all the tests. If you don't have this, add it.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid plurality.

I created fixture with a name "users.yml" for User model.

And I created fixture called "group.yml" for Group model.

Both naming is good apparently. However, it creates a finder which has the same name as a file. So, the finder was group() vs groups()